# Возможно ли скрипт Python запустить в Hadoop, не используя парадигму, MapReduce?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, hadoop

Написал скрипт, который выполняет тематическую классификацию текстов по обучающей выборке fetch_20newsgroups с использованием библиотек sklearn. Входящие тексты, которые необходимо классифицировать, забираю из HDFS с помощью Spark. Если выполнять скрипт локально, не используя кластер Hadoop, а задействуя лишь HDFS в качестве хранилища - все работает. А мне необходимо этот скрипт выполнять непосредственно в кластере, чтобы в веб-интерфейсе отображалась как задача. Пробовал переписать под MapReduce, не получилось. Буду рад любым предложениям и советам. Заранее спасибо.

```
import os
import imp
import sys
import time
import datetime
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from pyspark import SparkContext
from datetime import datetime

def MNB():
    start_time_MNB = time.time() 
    clf_MNB = MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True).fit(X_train_tfidf, twenty_train.target)
    predicted = clf_MNB.predict(X_new_tfidf)
    filename = [x[0] for x in sorted(docs_new.collect())]
    stat_MNB = open('/home/hduser/stat_MNB.txt','w')
    result_MNB = {}
    for doc, category, file in zip(d_n, predicted, filename):
        print('%r => %s' % (doc, twenty_train.target_names[category]))
        stat_MNB.write('{0} \t {1} \t {2} \n'.format(file, twenty_train.target_names[category], datetime.today()))
        result_MNB[doc] = twenty_train.target_names[category]
        file_path = str(file[34:])
        dst_path = "result/" + str(twenty_train.target_names[category])
    #    subprocess.run(["hadoop","dfs","-mv",file_path,dst_path])
    #subprocess.run(["hdfs","dfs","-put","/home/hduser/stat_MNB.txt","result"])
    text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()), ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), ('clf', MultinomialNB())])
    text_clf = text_clf.fit(twenty_train.data, twenty_train.target)
    twenty_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test')
    docs_test = twenty_test.data
    predicted = text_clf.predict(docs_test)
    kach_MNB = str(np.mean(predicted == twenty_test.target)*100)
    print(kach_MNB[:4]+'%')
    time_MNB = str(time.time()-start_time_MNB)
    print("%s seconds" % time_MNB[:4])

def SGD():
    start_time_SGD = time.time()
    clf_SGD = SGDClassifier(max_iter=4)
    clf_SGD = clf_SGD.fit(X_train_tfidf, twenty_train.target)
    predicted = clf_SGD.predict(X_new_tfidf)
    filename = [x[0] for x in sorted(docs_new.collect())]
    stat_SGD = open('/home/hduser/stat_SGD.txt','w')
    result_SGD = {}
    for doc, category, file in zip(d_n, predicted, filename):
        print('%r => %s' % (doc, twenty_train.target_names[category]))
        stat_SGD.write('{0} \t {1} \t {2} \n'.format(file, twenty_train.target_names[category], datetime.today()))
        result_SGD[doc] = twenty_train.target_names[category]
        file_path = str(file[34:])
        dst_path = "result/" + str(twenty_train.target_names[category])
    #    subprocess.run(["hadoop","dfs","-mv",file_path,dst_path])
    twenty_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test')
    model = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), clf_SGD)
    model = model.fit(twenty_train.data, twenty_train.target)
    labels = model.predict(twenty_test.data)
    kach_SGD = str(np.mean(labels == twenty_test.target)*100)
    print(kach_SGD[:4]+'%')    
    time_SGD = str(time.time()-start_time_SGD)
    print("%s seconds" % time_SGD[:4])
    mat = confusion_matrix(twenty_test.target,labels)
    sns.heatmap(mat.T, square=True, annot=True, fmt='d', cbar=True, xticklabels=twenty_train.target_names, yticklabels=twenty_train.target_names)
    plt.xlabel('true')
    plt.ylabel('predict')

def file_for_map():
    category = open('/home/hduser/category.txt','w')
    for cat in predicted:
        rubrica = twenty_train.target_names[cat]
        #result.append(rubrica)
        result = str(rubrica)
        category.write('{0} \t {1} \n'.format(result, 1))
        print('%s\t%s' % (result, 1))
    subprocess.run(["hadoop","dfs","-put","/home/hduser/category.txt","input"])

#def reduce1(result):
#    curr_rubrica = {}
#    for line in result:
#        curr_rubrica[line] = curr_rubrica.get(line, 0) + 1
#    print(curr_rubrica)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #while (True):
    #    time.sleep(900)
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    docs_new = sc.wholeTextFiles(path='hdfs://127.0.1.1:9000/user/hduser/test', minPartitions=None, use_unicode='utf-8')
    if (docs_new.count() == 0):
        sys.exit("файлы не найдены")
    twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
    q = docs_new.map(lambda x: x[1])
    d_n = q.collect()
    X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(d_n)
    X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)
    clf_MNB = MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True).fit(X_train_tfidf, twenty_train.target)
    predicted = clf_MNB.predict(X_new_tfidf)
    result = []
    file_for_map()
    reduce1(result)
    MNB()
    SGD()
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия Spark?

Answer (score 1):

В последних версиях Spark ML реализованы методы [TFIDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf) и [Naive Bayes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-naive-bayes.html).

Пример использования TFIDF:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer

sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0.0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
    (0.0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
    (1.0, "Logistic regression models are neat")
], ["label", "sentence"])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)

hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=20)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
# alternatively, CountVectorizer can also be used to get term frequency vectors

idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)

rescaledData.select("label", "features").show()
```

Пример использования `Naive Bayes`:

```
from pyspark.mllib.classification import NaiveBayes, NaiveBayesModel
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils



# Load and parse the data file.
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

# Split data approximately into training (60%) and test (40%)
training, test = data.randomSplit([0.6, 0.4])

# Train a naive Bayes model.
model = NaiveBayes.train(training, 1.0)

# Make prediction and test accuracy.
predictionAndLabel = test.map(lambda p: (model.predict(p.features), p.label))
accuracy = 1.0 * predictionAndLabel.filter(lambda pl: pl[0] == pl[1]).count() / test.count()
print('model accuracy {}'.format(accuracy))

# Save and load model
output_dir = 'target/tmp/myNaiveBayesModel'
shutil.rmtree(output_dir, ignore_errors=True)
model.save(sc, output_dir)
sameModel = NaiveBayesModel.load(sc, output_dir)
predictionAndLabel = test.map(lambda p: (sameModel.predict(p.features), p.label))
accuracy = 1.0 * predictionAndLabel.filter(lambda pl: pl[0] == pl[1]).count() / test.count()
print('sameModel accuracy {}'.format(accuracy))
```

Comment: Spark 2.3.1. И под Spark'ом у меня он тоже работает. Мне надо, чтобы можно было этот скрипт запустить как задачу в кластере. Либо делать из него MapReduce, что у меня не получается за недостатком опыта программирования, либо как-то можно запустить его целиком с помощью утилиток

Comment: @ИгнатийАнтонов, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

Comment: Спасибо) А необходимо ли мне из .py в .jar переделывать?\

Comment: @ИгнатийАнтонов, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120011/using-spark-submit-with-python-main

Comment: Я сейчас попробовал, в менеджере ресурсов задача отобразилась, но она завершилась со статусом FAILED. Когда я запускаю просто spark-submit --master local ... .py все работает. Не знаете с чем может связано?

Comment: И с .jar я не понял до конца